# Multiple authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Back in ASP.NET Core 1, authentication would be hooked manually into the request pipeline on its configuration: For a custom authentication process, you would simply define a `AuthenticationMiddleware` and hook it into your pipeline at the point where the authentication was supposed to happen.

In ASP.NET Core 2, there's no more `AuthenticationMiddleware` and you're supposed to do a `UseAuthentication()` at some point in the pipeline where *all* authentication necessarily happens.

The difference is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme

To distinguish different ways of authentication, there are policies identified by magic strings (lots of magic strings in ASP.NET Core).

I'm then told that I can select the desired scheme with attributes on my controller, but I don't use MVC at all in the scenario in question. So how do I specify for a specific branch of the pipeline:

```
    app.UseWhen(c => ..., app2 =>
    {
        // auth number 1 desired

        ...
    });

    app.UseWhen(c => ..., app2 =>
    {
        // auth number 2 desired

        ...
    });
```

And even in MVC, authentication happens before routing, so how can the information which scheme to use possibly be available at the `UseAuthentication()` point in the pipeline?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what you want to do in your middleware? e.g. Return a 401 if the user wasn't authenticated, etc?

Comment: @KirkLarkin It’s just reading the headers and returns a 403 if authentication fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target a specific authentication-scheme using an imperative approach, by calling [`AuthenticateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.authenticateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's an example:

```
app2.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    var authenticateResult = await ctx.AuthenticateAsync("SchemeName");

    if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401; // e.g.
        return;
    }

    // ...
});
```

`AuthenticateAsync` takes the authentication-scheme as an argument and returns an instance of [`AuthenticateResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticateresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which indicates success or failure via `Succeeded` and provides the authenticated `ClaimsPrincipal` via [`Principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticateresult.principal?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticateResult_Principal).

You can also perform authorisation against a specific policy using [`IAuthorizationService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice.authorizeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's an example of how the `Principal` from `AuthenticateResult` can be passed through `AuthorizeAsync`:

```
var authorizationService = ctx.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthorizationService>();
var authorizationResult = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
    authenticateResult.Principal, "PolicyName");

if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded)
{
    ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403; // e.g.
    return;
}

// ...
```

As with `AuthenticateResult`, [`AuthorizationResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) indicates success or failure via `Succeeded` - it also provides information about why authorisation failed via [`Failure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationresult.failure?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authorization_AuthorizationResult_Failure).