# .NET Core Authorization - Service Layer Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I'm looking into [.NET Core authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and all examples are related do MVC/WebAPI controllers which support `Authorize` attribute.

I was wondering if there is a way to have Authorize attribute on other, "non-controller" methods so that I could authorize call to specific service method? I know one should have authorization at access level (controller level), but since service layer should be shared and we could have multiple access points to the application (not only controllers) my approach is to do whole authorization within controllers.

1. Can I somehow use `Authorize` attribute on service layer methods?
2. Is there some kind of service that enables direct authorization from code (not necessarily for specific resource but for example check if user has `Admin.Full` permission - actually same thing as `Authorize` attribute but inside method body)?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55599595/2630078) should be enough to get you started. In terms of accessing `HttpContext` inside of a service, look at [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) if you haven't already.

Comment: I was not aware that IAuthorizationService had overloads without need to pass Object (resource). I'll take a look into this.

Comment: Let me know if you need more specific help.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Related to Authorize attribute on methods - I guess thats not supported out of the box? I'd need to create my own attribute and then intercept any call to specific class/interface, check for attributes and then invoke authorization flow if Authorize attribute is present?

Comment: No, it's not supported. The `Authorize` attribute is only respected by the ASP.NET Core components (controllers, razor pages, etc).

Comment: You can use this to wrap your classes in a Proxy, and intercept methods based on an attribute - its completely agnostic of any web technologies too.. : https://github.com/f135ta/SimpleProxy .. (I wrote it)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it because thats what I needed.